# Unable to connect to linux server

Tags: linux, logging, boot

I tried to connect to my Linux server as root via ssh, and then when it asks me for a password I get this error message :

```
login:status code retuned 0xc00000b5 NT_SATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
CIFS VFS:send error in SessSetup= -5 usb 1-4 :USB disconnected, 
device number 3 usb 1-4.1 :USB disconnected, device number 4  IPv6:udp checksum is 0
```

The problem is that my connection is accepted but I cannot type any command in the command line, and actually the server hangs and I cannot even restart it via command line.
Is there any way to fix that or to force restart without being connected physically to the server or maybe through an another server as a proxy?

Comment: Before rebooting the server, could you add more informations about the PAM process ? Is it based on Samba ? Why is it a USB information ? Do you put your filesystem on USB key ?

Comment: yes it is based on Samba and and not sure if the files sytem are stored in a USB key and I cannot check it because as I said I cannot perform any action in my server

Comment: You might need to boot into Single-User mode (or off of a Live-Boot image) and dig into the logs.  The usual suspects (root's entry in /etc/passed, the /etc/nsswitch.conf, /var/log/messages) and so forth) would be helpful.